# How would one derive a theoretical anti-entropic force equation?

Tags: entropy

How would one imagine and formulate a theoretical force that counteracts the second law of thermodynamics?

I'm not conceptualizing a force that merely pauses Entropy, but a force that creates order, Ala the force at the causal origin of the 'big bang'.

Is order exclusively the emergent product of multiple forces branching from an asymmetry; or can there be a quantum force that imparts structure, not just as emergent property, but as expression of said force.

I suppose my concept is of an informational algorithm manifested as quantum particle.

Comment: My fridge does that all day long... if you neglect that it has to consume electricity. Not sure what you are asking. How to make unphysical models? It's as simple as turning a sign around in a physical one. Take a simple linear heat conductivity law and reverse the sign.